# automated way to check if url loads but not actually run app django?

Tags: python, django, scripting

I have a django app writing django app that's my main portfolio demo. I call a cool API that highlights your code for you, but what it returns sometimes blows up in django and I don't wanna troubleshoot this for months. I do want a script to test all my urls one by one, which I already have as the app_writer writes them, and I was wondering how in django you pretend to runserver, call each url, and return the response 200 or what before gutting bad templates/links.  Has anyone done this, and what was the general thing? It seems to me I have to write an external script using requests and scrape it one-by-one, from a different terminal while this one runs. That isn't an option as it's just a demo, I wanna do it inside the app.

Thank you

Comment: You can use django test client to test the URL https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client

Comment: wow that's sweet. phrase it as an answer if you'd like me to accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) can send request and designed to test your application. Here is quick example.

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'john', 'password': 'smith'})
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> response = c.get('/customer/details/')
>>> response.content
'<!DOCTYPE html...'
```